# Is there a Selenium equivalent to BeautifulSoup's has_attr() function?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

For instance, if needing to check whether an element has a `class` attribute (Where it is `element.has_attr("class")` in bs4), how could this be done in Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.get_attribute()` method and check to see if the result is `None` like this:

```
x = element.get_attribute('class')
if x is not None:
    # then it has the attribute!
else:
    # it doesn't have the attribute =(
```